Configuration of jooq-codegen-gradle in a Kotlin project
I've revised documentation but the documentation is relatively unclear as to how one would include the generated JOOQ files as part of their project. When generating the files, I found the project is not able to compile, given it cannot find the generated classes. There's no clear guidance that I could find in the documentation, except for "ensure that its in your classpath".
I'm using the jooq-codegen-gradle plugin in a completely new project and I managed to solve this issue using sourceSets, but I'm unsure whether this is the way to go. I'm attaching my Gradle build file (no Gradle guru here). Would appreciate having it revised and to know whether instead of sourceSets, another way should be used.
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.23"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.23"
    id("org.jooq.jooq-codegen-gradle") version "3.19.7"

}

group = "org.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

jooq {
    configuration {
        jdbc {
            driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
            url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/timeline"
            user = "postgres"
            password = "postgres"

        }

        generator {
            database {
                name = "org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase"
                inputSchema = "public"
            }

            target {
                packageName = "org.example.jooqscratch.generated"
                directory = "build/generated-src/jooq/main"
            }
        }
    }

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    this.main{
        kotlin.srcDir("${layout.buildDirectory.get()}/generated-src/jooq/main")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:10.12.0")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-database-postgresql:10.12.0")
    jooqCodegen("org.postgresql:postgresql")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

Tried revising the documentation to find a clear path. Tried using latest versions on a completely new project to ensure everything is aligned. Tried checking configurations.

Correction: it fails with sourceSets to compile with the error "Unresolved reference: generated"

Add this:
tasks.named("compileKotlin") {
    dependsOn(tasks.filter { it.name.startsWith("jooqCodegen") }.toTypedArray())
}


Still doesn't seem to get picked up by the IDE

There's a bug, probably in IntelliJ, see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-350872/JOOQ-Plugin-No-Longer-Works-With-IntelliJ-Idea, https://groups.google.com/g/jooq-user/c/WYKlwguBHwE/m/27Z4w8cKAQAJ. If the build works this way, then the IDE shouldn't report problems.
